# How does one count the number of unique connections of a network in python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I need to count the number of unique connections in a network that allows for duplicate and self-connections.

Previous questions all focus on finding duplicates in a single flat array or removing them. I am at a loss as for how I would apply such techniques to the following:

```
source =      [1, 6, 1, 8, 7, 5, 0, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 0, 6, 2, 2, 1, 6, 4]
destination = [8, 8, 8, 7, 5, 1, 8, 0, 8, 2, 4, 5, 7, 3, 5, 7, 2, 0, 5, 5]
```

The network's connections are represented in 2 python arrays. For example, node 1 connects to node 8, node 8 connects to node 6, and so on. These connections are directional. This particular network has 9 nodes and 20 connections, but other networks have MANY more.

All that should be returned by `def countUnique(source, destination)` is the integer count of unique connections.

Comment: No. I want a numerical count of all non-duplicate connections. How do you mean "difference?"

Comment: First I would produce tuples of connections `[(1, 8), (6, 8), ...]` (can be done with `zip`) then there is the set data type to find unique connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len(set(zip(source, destination)))`

`zip(source, destination)` returns pairs of `source` and `destination`

`set(...)` returns a Python set with only unique elements

`len(...)` returns the set length - the number of all unique edges

P.S. I suggest you to use a some good Python graph library, like [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/). Such libraries have a huge amount of useful functions and algorithms for graph processing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter` from `collections` and `zip` tuples.

```
from collections import Counter
list = zip(source, destination)
count = Counter(list)
```

Result:

```
Counter({(6, 5): 3, (1, 8): 2, (6, 8): 1, (8, 7): 1, (7, 5): 1, (5, 1): 1, (0, 8): 1, (3, 0): 1, (8, 8): 1, (4, 2): 1, (5, 4): 1, (5, 7): 1, (0, 3): 1, (2, 7): 1, (2, 2): 1, (1, 0): 1, (4, 5): 1})
```